# Python split users input

Tags: python, split

```
# Enter Function
def enter(self,newval):
    self.value = newval

# Add Function
def add(self,newval):
    self.value += newval

# Subtract Function
def subtract(self,newval):
    self.value -= newval

class Accumulator:
def __init__(self,newval = 0):
    self.value = newval

    acc = Accumulator()

    if operator == 'e' or operator == 'E':
        acc.enter(newval)
    elif operator == 'a' or operator == 'A':
        acc.add(newval)
    elif operator == 's' or operator == 'S':
        acc.subtract(newval)


calculator = input("Enter a number, followed by a space, then a valid operator: ").split
```

I am trying to take the users input to create a calculator like idea. I understand how I can take 1 value of input but I don't know how to take 2 values of input "or split" and set them equal to my problem above If the user enters "5 a" it will set 5 as the (newval) value and call to the add function. If the user enters "5 s" it will set 5 as the (newval) value and call to the subtract function and eventually print out the accumulating total.

Comment: is it python2 or python3? because input() in two versions is different

Comment: You might not want to put that logic directly in `__init__()`, instead put it in a method `operation(val, oper)`, which you can invoke with the results of `input(...).split()`. Otherwise you can only ever perform an operation when you create the calculator. You can always call `operation()` from `__init__(..., string)`

Comment: To "split" a string, all you have to do is call its `split` method: `number, operator = calculator.split()`. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Of course you still need to convert number to an `int` or `float`, and you may want some error handling. Also, you've got a bunch of methods that you defined outside the class, which isn't going to work, and you almost certainly don't want to create a new `Accumulator` instance inside the constructor for the `Accumulator` class, so… just fixing the one problem isn't going to make everything suddenly work.

Comment: I got it based on past input... I was looking for input(...).split() Thanks for the fast responses..

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how to take 2 values of input "or split" and set them …

The way to split a string is with its [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method.

So:

```
number, operator = calculator.split()
```

By default, `split` splits on any whitespace; to split on just a single space, use `split(' ')`.

Also, `split` will return as many values as there are words. This means if the user types `123 + *` or `123+`, you'll get an exception about trying to unpack 3 or 1 values into 2 targets. You can handle that with a `try`/`except`, or you can store the result in a list and check its `len`, or you can use [`partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) to guarantee that you get exactly two words.

```
number, _, operator = calculator.partition(' ')
```